# When to use UI Plugin or PlaceHolder

Tags: nativescript

As far as I have understood so far, one can create a custom (native) UI component by following the guide in the [NativeScript UI Plugin documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin)

But there is also this [PlaceHolder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder) that can be added into the XML and then instantiate a custom UI component to be displayed in it.

So what are the differences between both and when to use each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely your decision. In my opinion, if you are going to reuse the component and want to share with the community then make a plugin. There is no right or wrong answer to be honest :)

Comment: Thanks! So even in terms of data binding they are equivalent or is there any limitation when going with the placeholder instead of the UI plugin way?

Comment: Well the custom component is probably a better route in terms of databinding. I'm not aware of any limitations of achieving databinding with a placeholder component but I think it would be a bit involved.